# How to access a different collection within a firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I promise i thoroughly checked through all the previous asked questions and there isn't anything similar to this. I have a firebase function that listens to onCreate on a firestore collection.

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.firestore.document('/Users/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const username = snap.data().username;
        const email = snap.data().email;

        console.log(username, email)

        const mailRef = functions.firestore.document('/mail')
        return mailRef.ref.set({
            email: email,
            subject: 'Welcome'

        });


    });
```

After a document is created in `Users`, i want to take the data in users and create a new document in a main collection called `mail`. Is this possible because i've read the docs like 10 times and there's nothing on this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Comment: when i remove 'ref' i get TypeError: mailRef.set is not a function

Comment: You'll have to figure out exactly which document you want to write to. `/mail` is not a full document path.  "mail" might be a collection, but you'll need a document ID to write to as well.  Or maybe accept a random document ID.  What specifically are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm trying to create a document with a random id with those fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a document in cloud functions, then you need to use the admin sdk, so first install the package:

```
npm install firebase-admin --save
```

initialize the admin sdk:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

const db = admin.firestore();
```

Then you can add:

```
       const mailRef = db.collection('mail')
        return mailRef.add({
            email: email,
            subject: 'Welcome'

        });
```

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#add

Comment: That still doesn't work. Im getting this TypeError: functions.firestore.collection is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming a bit late, just incase anyone found themselves with this same question.When you use set() to create a document, you must specify an ID for the document to create. so basically the above code just takes a little tweak as follows

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.firestore.document('/Users/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const username = snap.data().username;
        const email = snap.data().email;
        const uid  = context.params.documentId  //get the doc ID
        const alternateUid = //you can generate a random ID here
        console.log(username, email)

        const mailRef = firestore.collection("mail").doc(uid)
        return mailRef.set({
            email: email,
            subject: 'Welcome'
        });
    });
```

But sometimes there isn't a meaningful ID for the document or you don't want to use any of the above. Then it's more convenient to let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you. You can do this by calling add(), as such

```
const mailRef = firestore.collection("mail")
    return mailRef.add({
        email: email,
        subject: 'Welcome'
    })
```